# GDPR compliance for software that lets users store PII of other people

Tags: european-union, gdpr

Most times you see GDPR it relates to the first party storing data about their users, customers, whatever. I'm a developer for some hosted software (SaaS if you will) that allows —as a very tangential feature— users to store a personal address book of their contacts.

- Is that legal now?
- Do we have to consent every third party contact before they're added into the address book of one of our users?
- More worryingly, do we have to respond to personal data requests from contacts? For example, would we have to reveal *who* had added them to their address book?

We are within the EU, operating solely within the EU for now.